# Image URL Rewrite via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I Have URL like this, site.com/img/index.php?id=ID. I want to rewrite this to site.com/img/ID/title.jpg

Here is .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /img/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Url Format is Like This site.com/index.php?id=ID&title=title.jpg
Remember .jpg extension is fixed you can remove this.

Try This Code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /img/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=([^\s]+)&title=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?/([^/]+).jpg$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```